# Keyboard shortcut to add block comment in Xcode 9?

Tags: ios, markup, xcode9

I am adding documentation to project, but do not find any shortcut to add Block Comment. I have read [Markup Formatting Reference guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/ComentBlock.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH103-SW1) but not able to find shortcut.

I am using `Option ⌥` + `Command ⌘` + `/` to add comment but it adding `///` for every line.

```
    /// Initializer
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - userId: User Id
    ///   - userName: User Name
    ///   - applicationVersion: Applicarion Version

    init(_ userId: String, withUserName userName: String, withApplicationVersion applicationVersion: String)
```

I want to add Block Comment `/** ....*/` as below:

```
/**
 - parameters:
   - cubes: The cubes available for allocation
   - people: The people that require cubes
 */
```

Answer (score 2):

1.Create Automator service using AppleScript

2.Make sure "Output replaces selected text" is checked

3.Enter the following code:

```
 on run {input, parameters}
 return "/*\n" & (input as string) & "*/"
 end run
```

Now you can access that service through Xcode - Services menu or giving it a shortcut under System Preferences.